# C# JSON deserialization trying to deserialize into an array of KeyValuePairs when i pass a JSON object to it

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have got an error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,Tessa.Extensions.Shared.Acquiring.AcqFieldData]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

when i pass a JSON array string (settings) to the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<String, AcqFieldData>>(settings)`

and the other error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,Tessa.Extensions.Shared.Acquiring.AcqFieldRef][]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

when i pass a JSON object string as an input. Here is my two inputs, array:

```
[
  {
    "eca31ead-e905-43af-b92d-d5c01eccb590": {
      "Fields": {
        "EquipmentManufacturerName": {
          "CardID": "3ae9344f-00f7-4760-a790-4b5375807791",
          "Section": "AcqEquipmentManufacturerCards",
          "Field": "Name",
          "Value": "ref"
        },
        "EquipmentManufacturerID": {
          "CardID": null,
          "Section": null,
          "Field": null,
          "Value": "3ae9344f-00f7-4760-a790-4b5375807791"
        },
        "IsClientEquipment": {
          "CardID": null,
          "Section": null,
          "Field": null,
          "Value": false
        },
        "ServiceCatID": {
          "CardID": null,
          "Section": null,
          "Field": null,
          "Value": null
        },
        "ServiceCatName": {
          "CardID": null,
          "Section": null,
          "Field": null,
          "Value": null
        }
      },
      "ReadonlyControlAliases": null
    }
  },
  {
    "67830499-876a-4e2c-a08d-fd6100349b99": {
      "Fields": {
        "ClassBName": {
          "CardID": "0fb18fa1-8560-4364-9a16-03815f5e9303",
          "Section": "AcqClassBCards",
          "Field": "Name",
          "Value": "ref"
        },
        "ClassBID": {
          "CardID": null,
          "Section": null,
          "Field": null,
          "Value": "0fb18fa1-8560-4364-9a16-03815f5e9303"
        },
        "TerminalTypeName": {
          "CardID": "7c081fbf-13e6-4949-a634-85d7a99ebe01",
          "Section": "AcqTerminalTypeCards",
          "Field": "Name",
          "Value": "ref"
        },
        "TerminalTypeID": {
          "CardID": null,
          "Section": null,
          "Field": null,
          "Value": "7c081fbf-13e6-4949-a634-85d7a99ebe01"
        },
        "EquipmentManufacturerName": {
          "CardID": "3ae9344f-00f7-4760-a790-4b5375807791",
          "Section": "AcqEquipmentManufacturerCards",
          "Field": "Name",
          "Value": "ref"
        },
        "EquipmentManufacturerID": {
          "CardID": null,
          "Section": null,
          "Field": null,
          "Value": "3ae9344f-00f7-4760-a790-4b5375807791"
        },
        "FloorLimitSum": {
          "CardID": null,
          "Section": null,
          "Field": null,
          "Value": null
        },
        "FloorLimit": {
          "CardID": null,
          "Section": null,
          "Field": null,
          "Value": false
        },
        "CreditVaucherSum": {
          "CardID": null,
          "Section": null,
          "Field": null,
          "Value": null
        },
        "CreditVaucher": {
          "CardID": null,
          "Section": null,
          "Field": null,
          "Value": false
        },
        "MotoSof": {
          "CardID": null,
          "Section": null,
          "Field": null,
          "Value": false
        },
        "Preauthorization": {
          "CardID": null,
          "Section": null,
          "Field": null,
          "Value": false
        },
        "IsClientEquipment": {
          "CardID": null,
          "Section": null,
          "Field": null,
          "Value": true
        },
        "ServiceCatID": {
          "CardID": null,
          "Section": null,
          "Field": null,
          "Value": null
        },
        "ServiceCatName": {
          "CardID": null,
          "Section": null,
          "Field": null,
          "Value": null
        }
      },
      "ReadonlyControlAliases": [
        "ClassB",
        "TerminalType",
        "EquipmentManufacturer",
        "FloorLimitSum",
        "FloorLimit",
        "CreditVaucherSum",
        "CreditVaucher",
        "MotoSof",
        "Preauthorization",
        "IsClientEquipment"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "9560cc34-822e-430a-9a42-0eccb6d052f2": {
      "Fields": {
        "EquipmentTemplate": {
          "CardID": null,
          "Section": null,
          "Field": null,
          "Value": "GPRS"
        },
        "TerminalTypeName": {
          "CardID": "7c081fbf-13e6-4949-a634-85d7a99ebe01",
          "Section": "AcqTerminalTypeCards",
          "Field": "Name",
          "Value": "ref"
        },
        "TerminalTypeID": {
          "CardID": null,
          "Section": null,
          "Field": null,
          "Value": "7c081fbf-13e6-4949-a634-85d7a99ebe01"
        },
        "IsClientEquipment": {
          "CardID": null,
          "Section": null,
          "Field": null,
          "Value": false
        },
        "ServiceCatID": {
          "CardID": null,
          "Section": null,
          "Field": null,
          "Value": null
        },
        "ServiceCatName": {
          "CardID": null,
          "Section": null,
          "Field": null,
          "Value": null
        }
      },
      "ReadonlyControlAliases": [
        "EquipmentTemplate",
        "TerminalType",
        "IsClientEquipment"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

and object:

```
{
  "eca31ead-e905-43af-b92d-d5c01eccb590": {
    "Fields": {
      "EquipmentManufacturerName": {
        "CardID": "3ae9344f-00f7-4760-a790-4b5375807791",
        "Section": "AcqEquipmentManufacturerCards",
        "Field": "Name",
        "Value": "ref"
      },
      "EquipmentManufacturerID": {
        "CardID": null,
        "Section": null,
        "Field": null,
        "Value": "3ae9344f-00f7-4760-a790-4b5375807791"
      },
      "IsClientEquipment": {
        "CardID": null,
        "Section": null,
        "Field": null,
        "Value": false
      },
      "ServiceCatID": {
        "CardID": null,
        "Section": null,
        "Field": null,
        "Value": null
      },
      "ServiceCatName": {
        "CardID": null,
        "Section": null,
        "Field": null,
        "Value": null
      }
    },
    "ReadonlyControlAliases": null
  },
  "67830499-876a-4e2c-a08d-fd6100349b99": {
    "Fields": {
      "ClassBName": {
        "CardID": "0fb18fa1-8560-4364-9a16-03815f5e9303",
        "Section": "AcqClassBCards",
        "Field": "Name",
        "Value": "ref"
      },
      "ClassBID": {
        "CardID": null,
        "Section": null,
        "Field": null,
        "Value": "0fb18fa1-8560-4364-9a16-03815f5e9303"
      },
      "TerminalTypeName": {
        "CardID": "7c081fbf-13e6-4949-a634-85d7a99ebe01",
        "Section": "AcqTerminalTypeCards",
        "Field": "Name",
        "Value": "ref"
      },
      "TerminalTypeID": {
        "CardID": null,
        "Section": null,
        "Field": null,
        "Value": "7c081fbf-13e6-4949-a634-85d7a99ebe01"
      },
      "EquipmentManufacturerName": {
        "CardID": "3ae9344f-00f7-4760-a790-4b5375807791",
        "Section": "AcqEquipmentManufacturerCards",
        "Field": "Name",
        "Value": "ref"
      },
      "EquipmentManufacturerID": {
        "CardID": null,
        "Section": null,
        "Field": null,
        "Value": "3ae9344f-00f7-4760-a790-4b5375807791"
      },
      "FloorLimitSum": {
        "CardID": null,
        "Section": null,
        "Field": null,
        "Value": null
      },
      "FloorLimit": {
        "CardID": null,
        "Section": null,
        "Field": null,
        "Value": false
      },
      "CreditVaucherSum": {
        "CardID": null,
        "Section": null,
        "Field": null,
        "Value": null
      },
      "CreditVaucher": {
        "CardID": null,
        "Section": null,
        "Field": null,
        "Value": false
      },
      "MotoSof": {
        "CardID": null,
        "Section": null,
        "Field": null,
        "Value": false
      },
      "Preauthorization": {
        "CardID": null,
        "Section": null,
        "Field": null,
        "Value": false
      },
      "IsClientEquipment": {
        "CardID": null,
        "Section": null,
        "Field": null,
        "Value": true
      },
      "ServiceCatID": {
        "CardID": null,
        "Section": null,
        "Field": null,
        "Value": null
      },
      "ServiceCatName": {
        "CardID": null,
        "Section": null,
        "Field": null,
        "Value": null
      }
    },
    "ReadonlyControlAliases": [
      "ClassB",
      "TerminalType",
      "EquipmentManufacturer",
      "FloorLimitSum",
      "FloorLimit",
      "CreditVaucherSum",
      "CreditVaucher",
      "MotoSof",
      "Preauthorization",
      "IsClientEquipment"
    ]
  },
  "9560cc34-822e-430a-9a42-0eccb6d052f2": {
    "Fields": {
      "EquipmentTemplate": {
        "CardID": null,
        "Section": null,
        "Field": null,
        "Value": "GPRS"
      },
      "TerminalTypeName": {
        "CardID": "7c081fbf-13e6-4949-a634-85d7a99ebe01",
        "Section": "AcqTerminalTypeCards",
        "Field": "Name",
        "Value": "ref"
      },
      "TerminalTypeID": {
        "CardID": null,
        "Section": null,
        "Field": null,
        "Value": "7c081fbf-13e6-4949-a634-85d7a99ebe01"
      },
      "IsClientEquipment": {
        "CardID": null,
        "Section": null,
        "Field": null,
        "Value": false
      },
      "ServiceCatID": {
        "CardID": null,
        "Section": null,
        "Field": null,
        "Value": null
      },
      "ServiceCatName": {
        "CardID": null,
        "Section": null,
        "Field": null,
        "Value": null
      }
    },
    "ReadonlyControlAliases": [
      "EquipmentTemplate",
      "TerminalType",
      "IsClientEquipment"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my classes. AcqFieldData:

```
public class AcqFieldData
    {
        public readonly IDictionary<string, AcqFieldRef> Fields;
        public readonly IEnumerable<string> ReadonlyControlAliases;

        public AcqFieldData(
            IEnumerable<string> readonlyControlAliases, 
            params KeyValuePair<string, AcqFieldRef>[] fields)
        {
            this.ReadonlyControlAliases = readonlyControlAliases;

            this.Fields = new Dictionary<string, AcqFieldRef>();

            foreach (var pair in fields)
            {
                if (pair.Key != null)
                    this.Fields.Add(pair);
            }
        }
    }
```

and AcqFieldRef:

```
public class AcqFieldRef
    {
        public readonly Guid? CardID;
        public readonly string Section;
        public readonly string Field;
        public readonly Object Value;

        public AcqFieldRef(Guid cardID, string section, string field)
        {
            this.CardID = cardID;
            this.Section = section;
            this.Field = field;
            this.Value = "ref";
        }

        public AcqFieldRef(Object value)
        {
            if (value as String == "ref")
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    "Value \"ref\" is reserved for a link description");
            }

            this.Value = value;
        }

        [UsedImplicitly]
        public AcqFieldRef()
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you perhaps post your classes, this would help.

Comment: I would recommend using [Json2CSharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to create your classes from that `json`... There's not enough classes, are wrong, and you'll run into more issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First json you have is not a `Dictionary<string, object>` but a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`.

I used dynamic to answer your question since there was no definition of the class, `AcqFieldData` in your question.

```
var value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>>(json);
```

and your Second json is `Dictionary<string, object>`.

```
var value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json);
```

This code works with dynamic object but not `AcqFieldData`. Your constructors seems to have some issues when trying to create / add objects and inserting them to your Dictionary. When I tested your code, it throws error in `foreach (var pair in fields)` when fields is null.

I would suggest trying out classes with getter and setter and go from there.

```
public class AcqFieldData
{
    public Dictionary<string, AcqFieldRef> Fields { get; set; }
    public List<string> ReadonlyControlAliases { get; set; }
}

public class AcqFieldRef
{
    public Guid? CardID { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public Object Value { get; set; }
}

// Use this in the main for 1st json
var jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, AcqFieldData>>>(json);

// Use this in the main for 2nd json
var jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, AcqFieldData>>(json);
```